# Numpy : overload str function to get exponential notation into all code

Tags: python, string, numpy, overloading

I would like to overload `str` function on a global point of view, i.e applying to each `str` used in my script.

I would like to work only with exponential notation all in my code with 15 digits. For example, I have:

```
str('%.15e' % 0.0010750942544107058)
```

which gives the string : `'1.075094254410706e-03'`

Ii it possible to do that without modifying each `str(float_value)` by `str('%.15e' % float_value)` ?

It would be a kind of overloading like in C++.

Comment: You _could_ but it’s likely to be quite troublesome to maintain. Replacing builtins is permitted but strongly not recommended in Python.

Comment: Just define a function with that name - `def str(s):...` - if you really want to do that.

Comment: `str(an_object)` translates to `an_object.__str__()`.  So each object class has its own `__str__` method.  So each class already overloads the base `object` class's method.  With `numpy.array2string` and `numpy.set_printoptions` you have chance of controlling this for arrays, but I think it will be hard(er) to change for base Python numbers.